# Move Folder into different Folder with VBS

Tags: vbscript

I've been trying to make a little VBS that gets all Home Directories on a Server and moves them to a different place. Little Example

C:\homefolders\test_person
C:\homefolders\test_person\old_home

Here is what I got so far, but the moving part doesn't work...

```
Call ListFolderContents("C:\Windows\System32\Drivers")

Sub ListFolderContents(path)
    set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    set folder = fs.GetFolder(path)
    Msgbox folder.path

    For each item in folder.SubFolders
        ListFolderContents(item.Path)
    Next
    set folder = Nothing
    set fs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't recall if VBS has the same command as VB6, but if so you can call : Name "<file or folder src>" "<file or folder dest>"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming there's no problem with permissions:

```
set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set folder = fs.GetFolder(path)
folder.Move newPath
```

Cheers

Comment: thanks, oddly enough if I move the folder I get a permission error, but if I copy them it works. In that case I'll just copy and then delete xD

Comment: The deny might rely just on the removal, so a removal won't resolve the problem.